# Need positive question record?

Tags: support

My new profile page has indicated my progress towards badges, and the recent one was "curious". The description (screenshot below) says

```
Ask a good question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record
```

I have met the first criterion over the past few months accumulating 5 questions with positive up-votes, but the progress summary says that I "need positive question record". I am not sure how to meet this second criterion as there is no description what needs to be done. Can anyone help to clarify?

Also, is it possible to include that information in the progress report to hint the user?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice idea, it could be worth asking on Meta.SE as it is wider ranging than SU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"maintain a positive question record"**

From http://meta.stackexchange.com question [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399):

> **Curious**
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
>
>   - Any open question that is not deleted and has a of score >= 1 is considered well-received
>   - Only days where all questions asked have been well-received, count ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-well-received-questions))
>   - **A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (total
>       questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >=
>       0.5. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!**